# Android Camera2 CameraAvailabilityHandler calls cameraAvailable then cameraUnavailable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I'm trying to adjust the [CameraKit](https://camerakit.io/) api so that it works with `Camera2` ( it's *so close* but not there ) and I have been having trouble with the camera getting disconnected, especially if the activity is closed then subsequently opened again.

To try and pre-empt this I have added a `CameraAvailableListener` so I can try and ensure we don't get caught out by the camera having disconnected. It looks a little like this:

```
    cameraManager.registerAvailabilityCallback(object: CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
        override fun onCameraAvailable(cameraDeviceId: String) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera available ( "+cameraDeviceId+" ) seeking "+cameraId)
            if ((cameraDeviceId == cameraId ) && errorState ) {
                errorState = false
            }
            super.onCameraAvailable(cameraDeviceId)
        }

        override fun onCameraUnavailable(cameraDeviceId: String) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera unavailable ( "+cameraDeviceId+" )  seeking "+cameraId+" already in error state? "+errorState)
            if ( cameraDeviceId == cameraId && !errorState ) {
                cameraOpen = false
                errorState = true
            }
            super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraDeviceId)
        }
    }, cameraHandler)
```

In my logs I see the following:

```
2019-03-26 12:53:46.140 17945-18066/com.myphotoapp I/Camera2.kt: Camera available ( 0 ) seeking 0
2019-03-26 12:53:46.140 17945-18066/com.myphotoapp I/Camera2.kt: Camera available ( 1 ) seeking 0
2019-03-26 12:53:46.144 17945-18066/com.myphotoapp E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
2019-03-26 12:53:46.150 17945-17959/com.myphotoapp E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-03-26 12:53:46.151 17945-17959/com.myphotoapp E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-03-26 12:53:46.166 17945-18066/com.myphotoapp I/Camera2.kt: Camera unavailable ( 0 )  seeking 0 already in error state? false
2019-03-26 12:53:46.167 17945-18066/com.myphotoapp I/Camera2.kt: Camera unavailable ( 0 )  seeking 0 already in error state? true
```

Now if I ignore the `onCameraUnavailable` calls it seems to work fine when the camera is available, but if they are uninformative why are they being raised at all, or is it because of those messages coming out of libc?

Is there any way to know whether the camera is actually available in this situation or do I just need to call `open` and hope for the best?